# C++ candidate function not viable?

Tags: c++, class

Why the following code doesn't compile:

```
B b1(1), b2(2), b3(3);
const B b4 = b1 + (b2 + b3);
```

Until I replace this:

```
B operator+(B& b) {
    return B(n + b.n);
}
```

with this:(I don't know why to write const the compiler suggested that)

```
B operator+(const B& b) {
    return B(n + b.n);
}
```

Errors I get:

> invalid operands to binary expression ('B' and 'B')
>
> note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st
>   argument
>
> note: candidate template ignored: could not match
>   'reverse_iterator' against 'B' operator+(typename
>   reverse_iterator<_Iter>::difference_type __n, const
>   reverse_iterator<_Iter>& __x)

Plus, why this works? (it's similar to the previous case)

```
bool Test(int x)
{
    return x==0;
}
Test(0);
```

Comment: Temporaries cannot bind to non-const l-value reference.

Comment: BTW, you still miss a `const`: `B operator+(const B& b) const`.

Comment: b1 and the rest are not temporaries @Jarod42

Comment: It works without the other const

Comment: `(b2+b3)` results in a temporary.

Comment: `b2 + b3` is a temporary. And to see the need for the second `const`, try (b1 + b2) + b3`.

Comment: Plus why changing the parameter (and not returning value) as const solves this? may someone post full answer, that doesn't make sense

Comment: @Jarod42 without the extra const I tried what you said and it worked fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: and without the extra `const`, `b4 + b1` would fail to compile. (sorry bad previous example).

Comment: The `Test` example at the end of your question is not similar to the other cases because it takes its parameter by value, not reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const B b4 = b1 + (b2 + b3);
> ```

According to the order of operations, the first subexpression to evaluate is `b2 + b3`. This invokes `B::operator+`, which returns a `B` object. More precisely, a *temporary* `B` object is returned, one that will be used to help evaluate this full expressions and then discarded. This is much like making notes on scratch paper as you work through a long calculation by hand.

The next subexpression to evaluate is `b1` plus the temporary object. This invokes `b1.operator+` with the temporary `B` object as the argument. When the operator's signature is

```
B operator+(B& b)
```

there is a problem because the C++ language states that [a non-`const` reference cannot bind to a temporary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object). That is, the reference parameter (`B& b`) does not match the temporary object. You can solve this by changing the reference from one that is not `const`-qualified to one that is.

```
B operator+(const B& b)
```

This version of the operator takes a `const` reference, which *can* bind to a temporary object. (Again, this is simply a rule of the language. You can debate the reasons for it, but the rule still stands.)

Note that this is not a full solution since addition tends to be symmetric. To accommodate the scenario where the left side of the parentheses is `const`-qualified, `*this` also needs to be `const`-qualified.

```
B operator+(const B& b) const
```

For more tips, see [the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719). You might find that you don't necessarily want `operator+` to be a member function.

Comment: Thanks, But (b2 + b3) + b1 worked without adding const for this

Comment: `(b2+b3)+b1` works (temporary is `*this`). It is `b4+b1` which fails (`b4` is `const`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Is that one of the weird things with temporaries? Bah. If you write solid code, you forget the intricacies of how bad the code has to get before it triggers an actual error...

Comment: @zoorish Sorry, I did not test the code before posting. I often do, but in this case mocking up `B` seemed like too much work. (That is supposed to imply that if you had provided a minimal definition of `B` in the question -- something I could copy -- I would have double-checked by passing the code through a compiler.)